# Problems in migrating network drive files to sharepoint online - log of failed transfer

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, network-drive

I am trying to migrate files (approx. 90000 files, total 50GB) from a company network drive to sharepoint online. However, many files failed to upload to sharepoint due to different issues including, an extra space in front of the file name or file name too long...etc.

Therefore, I would like to find out how can I get a log of failed transfer so that I can locate those files and rename those files before uploading again? I noticed that there are notifications right after each upload but those notifications tends to disappear quite quickly and sometimes it is not showing the full details.

Or if there is any way to compare the files before and after migration to ensure that no files are missing.

I only have very basic knowledge about sharepoint online and thus any help is much appreciated

Comment: How did you deploy the migration? Use migration tool like SPMT or anyway else? If you were using SPMT, you should have got Failure Summary Report. Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/using-the-sharepoint-migration-tool-reports

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you are hitting the throttling limit. You may see 407 error if issue with throttling. I would suggest you upload the files in small batches and also use multiple accounts to upload the files